# "Can you please do this?" versus "Can you do this please?"

Tags: questions, politeness, word-order

What is the difference between these two phrases:

> Can you please do this?

> Can you do this please?

Is the latter one (putting an extra emphasis on *please*), considered to be a less polite and a more direct form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is absolutely no difference between them with regard to politeness. English is just not that sensitive to politeness: we don't have the finely-striated levels of politeness of, say, Japanese. Context and tone of voice can change any of them from a very polite request to a direct order with a veneer of politeness.

There is a **slight** difference in meaning, or at least emphasis. "Can you please do this" emphasizes the request, while "Can you do this please" emphasizes the task: the former asks you to do *something*, but what that something *is* is not that important. The latter asks you to do *this*, not *that*. However, this difference is very, very slight. And again, context and tone of voice can drastically change the interpretation.

Comment: I would think that if you're *intending* to sound somewhat irritated, by far the most likely position would be *"Can you **please** be quiet?"* I know I'm distorting that by typographically placing the stress on the words as written, but it still seems to me that sequence is inherently more "exasperated" than putting the word *please* in any other position.